# Determine IP Address outgoing request comes from

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, networking, ip-address

If I have a link in an MVC application hosted on Azure:

```
<a href="https://aThirdPartySoapWebService">Call web service</a>
```

At the moment we are having difficulty connecting to the URL, which is a SOAP web service.  We get an error 'site cannot be reached'.

Just to rule something out - what IP address would the service see this request coming from - my local (browser) or the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request would come from your IP.

Comment: thanks, but if I call the web service via, say a controller, it would be the server?

Comment: @davy, except for NAT, IP addresses don't change from end to end.

Comment: @davy A server would not use an <a href>, that is HTML and would indicate a standard browser, therefore the IP of the person visiting the site. If the webserver initiates http communication as a background process, it would be the IP address of the server. Re-reading your question, I am not sure why you would be calling a soap service in that manner. If you are presenting that URL on your MVC view, it would be the client that calls it.

Comment: @chris, We have a URL that is saying 'site cannot be reached' - the vendor requires white listed  various IPs, which we have given.  We are trying to troubleshoot but I'm sure the problem is at the vendors end.   In  nutshell, some colleagues thought a link would prove that we couldn't connect from a white listed IP - some of us thought that it would use the local IP.

Comment: so to avoid any confusion - do not try and call a service like I did in my question.

Comment: Can you RDP onto the server itself and open the endpoint in a browser, that would confirm that you can at least see it from the machine.

Comment: I asked my colleague to try that. I'm not sure how it us setup in Azure. I gave quickly coded up something to call the service from a controller and I'm deploying it now.  On my local machin, which isnt white listed - it says 'the remote machine actively refused...' so when I deploy Ill hopefully get a better error and can even remote debug.